# Switch character position using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string for example:

```
var string = 'This is a test sentence. Switch the characters. i .';
```

I want to switch position of every occurrence of the letter 'i' with the character following it except if the following character is a 't' or a non character like 'spaces' or 'line breaks'. So the result output should be some thing like:

```
Thsi si a test sentence. Switch the characters. i . // switches 's' but not 't' and 'space'
```

Is such a task possible with regular expressions? The characters I am working with are unicode characters. 'i' is just for an example. Which means matching all characters isn't a good idea. May be a ***not*** expression? I have tried some looping replaces but these aren't elegant (or efficient). Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a replace with a regex of that form:

```
var string = 'This is a test sentence. Switch the characters. i .';
var result = string.replace(/(i)(?![t\s])(.)/g, "$2$1");
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wB7N6/)

`(i)` matches and captures `i` into the variable `$1`.

`(?![t\s])` prevents the matching of `t` and space.

`(.)` matches and captures any other character into the variable `$2`.

Comment: Elegant one liner solution. Works great.

Comment: This is great. I am sorry but I am weak with regex. How does this change if let's say we want to check the preceding character?

Comment: @pewpewlasers You could perhaps use another capture group (JS unfortunately doesn't support lookbehinds). Let's say another condition to what we have is that when `i` is preceded by a space, no switching should be made. You could do: `string.replace(/(\S|^)(i)(?![t\s])(.)/g, "$1$3$2");` The `\S` will match a non-space, `^` will match the beginning of a line if the string is like `var string = 'island';`. The regex is going to match either `\S` or (indicated by `|`) `^`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex:`/(i)([^t\W])/gi`

**Code :**

```
var string = 'This is a test sentence. Switch the characters. i .';
string.replace(/(i)([^t\W])/gi,"$2$1");
```

**[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xV5rE9)**

**Explanation :**

[image]